# Multiple actions were found that match the request in webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, routes

I have controller with various actions and one of them is:

```
[HttpGet]
public IList<string> GetFoo(string id = null)
{ ... }
```

This action has individual route:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "GetFoos",
    routeTemplate: "api/my/foo/{_id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "My", action = "GetFoo" }
);
```

When I add another action:

```
[HttpGet]
public IList<string> GetBar()
{ ... }
```

Request to localhost/api/my/foo/ fails:

```
Multiple actions were found that match the request: 
↵System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[System.String] GetFoo(System.String) on type Controllers.MyController
↵System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[System.String] GetBar() on type Controllers.MyController"
```

Can someone explain please why this happens? I specified action = "GetFoo" for api/my/foo why it matches GetBar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be that you configure route as following, and request without ID - `/api/my/foo`.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "GetFoos",
    routeTemplate: "api/my/foo/{id}",
    defaults: new {controller = "My", action = "GetFoo"}
);

// Default 
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new {id = RouteParameter.Optional}
);
```

If so, ***first route doesn't match*** and fall throws to default route, but default route matches with ***multiple actions***.

***Note:*** GetFoos route will work if you request with ID explicitly - `/api/my/foo/1`

---

Ideally, if you see yourself using too many custom routes, you might want to consider using **Route Attribute** available in Web API 2, instead of creating individual route in Route config.

For example,

```
[RoutePrefix("Api/My")]
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("foo/{id:int}")]
    public IList<string> GetFoo(int id)
    {
        return new string[] {"Foo1-" + id, "Foo1-" + id};
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("bar/{id:int}")]
    public IList<string> GetBar(int id)
    {
        return new string[] {"Bar1-" + id, "Bar1-" + id};
    }
}
```